# how to interpret y-axis on QQ plots

Tags: r

I have a very simple question about qq plots:
my data :

then I plot normally QQ plot using `mardia` function from library `psych`:

```
mardia(ready,plot=TRUE)
```

I am confused about y-axis. according to [this source](https://www.statisticshowto.com/q-q-plots/#:~:text=The%20purpose%20of%20Q%20Q%20plots,come%20from%20the%20same%20distribution.&text=The%20image%20above%20shows%20quantiles,%2Dquantile%20(QQ)%20plot.): 
y-axis is my data points. however, I do not have any data point more than 7. why my plot has 9?
[image]

Comment: my data has 35 columns and 309 observations. each column contain values from 1 to 7, no NAs

Answer (score 0):

mardia plots the expected normal distribution values versus the Mahalanobis distance of the subjects.